# How to simplify this MATLAB code that calls a function on the output of a function on a cell array of double?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have this piece of code that is working but is kind of cumbersome. It has one argument which is a cell array and in each cell is a vector of double. All vectors have the same size. I need to calls a function on the output of a function on this variable. For example, here I call log() on all members in the double vector, then call sum() to sum everything. In actual code, the number of cells is much bigger. Is there a way to simplify this without using loops? Thanks!

```
>> cell_of_double{:}

ans =

    0.3140
    0.7160
    0.6925
    0.4265
    0.8875
    0.5785
    0.7185
    0.3275
    0.3030
    0.5745
    0.7435
    0.6930
    0.7290
    0.5660
    0.2750


ans =

    0.3620
    0.3580
    0.4760
    0.5560
    0.3245
    0.3785
    0.8805
    0.7600
    0.7580
    0.5435
    0.4985
    0.5830
    0.6155
    0.8010
    0.6150

>> cell_of_double

cell_of_double = 

    [15x1 double]
    [15x1 double]

>> sum(cellfun(@sum, cellfun(@(x) sum(arrayfun(@log, x)), cell_of_double(:), 'UniformOutput', false)))

ans =

  -18.6004
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the vectors within your cell are all the same size, you can collapse it into a matrix/vector. The way you're doing the operations on each cell is equivalent to doing it on a supervector. So instead of `cellfun`, you can do

```
dummyVector=cell2mat(cell_of_double);
output=sum(log(dummyVector));
```

Comment: Since `dummyVector` could be a column vector *or* a matrix (depending on whether the cell array is 1-by-2 or 2-by-1), you should reshape it into a column vector using the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) just to be safe: `output=sum(log(dummyVector(:)));`